# Is there a way to make RSpec fail if there is no assertion?

Tags: rspec

Minitest has `proveit!`

Does RSpec have a similar way to require assertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my take:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(Module.new do
                   attr_writer :expectation_set_count

                   def expectation_set_count
                     @expectation_set_count ||= 0
                   end

                   def expect(*)
                     self.expectation_set_count += 1

                     super
                   end
                 end)

  config.after do
    expect(expectation_set_count).to be > 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the RSpec for that, check this out:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/404#issuecomment-11431199 and http://blog.sorah.jp/2012/12/17/rspec-warn-for-no-expectations

Basically you need to set up `after` hook and check the metadata if there was an expectaiton run:
(copy of the code in case the url goes down)

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:each) do
    result = self.example.metadata[:execution_result]
    has_mock_expectations = RSpec::Mocks.space.instance_eval{receivers}.empty?
    if !result[:exception] && !result[:pending_message] && !RSpec::Matchers.last_should && hasnt_mock_expectations
      $stderr.puts "[WARN] No expectations found in example at #{self.example.location}: Maybe you forgot to write `should` in the example?"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: is there a mistake with the variable `has_mock_expectations`? You are using a local var called `hasnt_mock_expectations` but not `has_mock_expectations `... Also I get this when I run that `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError: 'example' is not available from within an example (e.g. an 'it' block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. 'before', 'let', etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a 'describe' or 'context' block).`